# LibGDX running error "ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: java, libgdx

I've created a Java LibGDX project in Eclipse and haven't edited anything other than the window's title and the dimensions of the window. When running the project it returns the following error: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/jnigen/NativeCodeGenerator
    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.BulletBuild.main(BulletBuild.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.NativeCodeGenerator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more`

I never used to have this issue and it has only just began occurring in this new project.

Code

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;


import de.matthiasmann.twlthemeeditor.Main;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.title = "AI Path Finding";
        config.width = Main.WIDTH;
        config.height = Main.HEIGHT;
        new LwjglApplication(new Game(), config);
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private final static int WIDTH = 800;
    private final static int HEIGHT = 800;

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using gradle integration?

Answer (score 0):

To develop your application via Eclipse, you need to install the

following pieces of software. You can find an in depth guide [HERE](http://www.toxsickproductions.com/libgdx/how-to-setup-your-libgdx-project/):

- **Java Development Kit 7+** (**JDK**) (6 will not work!): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
- **Android SDK**:                                                                                                                                                  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html
- **Android Development Tools for Eclipse**:
  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ (use this link as update site for eclipse)
- **Eclipse Integration Gradle**:
  http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/gradle/nightly (for
  Eclipse 4.4) or http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle (for
  Eclipse < 4.4)

**See also:**

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-(Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans)